# have call api data and Fateh in table view cell

Tags: swift, api, xcode13

i have run this code but not print any data in console and not get data in my api so no data display in may simulators

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        let url = URL(string: "https://gydo.me/api/api/User/index")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, response, error in
           guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
          //print(data)

            if error == nil {
                do{
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]{
                        print(json)
                   self.detail = try JSONDecoder().decode([apiData].self, from: data)
                       
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("JSON Error")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

}

func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        let url = URL(string: "https://gydo.me/api/api/User/index")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, response, error in
           guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
          //print(data)

            if error == nil {
                do{
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]{
                        print(json)
                   self.detail = try JSONDecoder().decode([apiData].self, from: data)
                       
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("JSON Error")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: `if let json = try JSONSerialization ... as? [String: Any]` contradicts `JSONDecoder().decode([apiData].self`. Ie, you are expecting to decode with `JSONDecoder` an Array, but with JSONSerialization a Dictionary. Remove the `if let json` line, or at least add an `else { print("Response is not a JSON OR a [String: Any]"); print("Received content: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")}`

Comment: According to the URL, it seems to be a `Dictionary` at top level, so `print(json)` should be called. But is `error` not `nil`? Is `data` not nil?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Iboutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var apiDataTableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Varaible
    var apiData = [DataModel]()

    // MARK: - Life CYcle Method
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        intlizer()
    }

    // MARK: - Intlization
    func intlizer() {
        downloadJSON {
            self.apiDataTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Make A Api Call
    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        let url = URL(string: "https://gydo.me/api/api/User/index")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, response, error in
              guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
             //print(data)

               if error == nil {
                   do{
                      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                      let decodedData = try 
decoder.decode(ApiDataModel.self, from: data)
                      self.apiData = decodedData.message
                      print(self.apiData)
                      
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           completed()
                      }
                   } catch {
                       print("JSON Error")
                   }
               }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

above is my viewcontroller

> This is my model for api data

```
// MARK: - Model
struct ApiDataModel: Decodable {
    var success: Bool
    var message: [DataModel]
}

struct DataModel: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var ip_address: String
    var access_token: String
}
```

if you want more data then you can add variable and use name same as api data name

> if you don't want to use same as api data name so you can write like this

```
struct DataModel: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var ip_address: String
    var access_token: String

    enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case ipAddress = "ip_address"
        case accessToken = "access_token"
    }
}
```

> And My tableView Screen Is Below
> [image]

I Hope You Need This